# Manually break ethernet frames

Tags: ethernet, cable

i have the next question: how can i manually create interference in fast ethernet cable or download the special program which will randomly corrupt ethernet frames (OS is not important)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your question is off-topic here, see the [help] for 'on' topics. Also, you can simply unplug the cable. Ethernet frames carry a FCS field with a CRC32 checksum, so any corrupted bit caused by analog problems will cause a frame to be dropped anyway.

Comment: @Zac67, Thanks for some help. If you mean *drop* that this frame will be removed from network, then there is not my case. I want to repeat case than such frame comes to custom device with custom implementation of network protocols (But i don't have the source code) and i need to watch the device behavior on such corrupted frames.

Comment: Corrupt ethernet frames will be dropped by the hardware before it enters a host. For example, a switch receiving a corrupted frame will simply drop it and not forward it toward the destination host. A destination host receiving a corrupted frame will have its interface drop the frame before it even enters the host. You need some special test gear to see such things on the wire, but that is really off-topic here. You could try to ask about that on [electronics.se].

Comment: @RonMaupin, I already realized that this question is off-topic. Just correct myself a little: this device has custom implementation of hardware too.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus if you want a quick-and-nasty test that a target on a lab bench device logs errors, you can can use an ordinary 2-pole relay fed at say 10 Hz to simulate plugging and unplugging.  Try it first against an another device for approximate error count.  It's statistical, but maybe that's enough.  For a proper answer, ask on [electronics.se].